# Magento - Multiple values of the same attribute on a product

Tags: magento, attributes, product

I would to have multiple values of the same attribute on a product in Magento.

E.g. I have a black-white blanket in my store. Customers should find this product when they select black, but also when they select white.

I saw there is an option called "Multiple Select" for admin input, but the option to use it for configurable products disappears.

So, is it possible for a product to have multiple values from the same attribute, but still use the attribute for configurable products?

I hope someone could help me!

Comment: You can't do that in Magento, that would take quite a lot of work to do something like that as well due to the way the configurable products work. That would not work in a generic way, what if you had more than one multiple box it would be impossible to work that way

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer. I think have to add the colors as black-white, instead of seperating them then.

Comment: Late, but yes @Mononootje you need to be explicit with each colour variant. You could also have a simple set of colours (black, white) and have it as a multi-select attribute as well which could be used for filtering. You could then assign both colours to a product using that attribute instead.